# Identify true activeElement in a frame hierarchy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm looking for a way to get the focused input of any page with the goal to update it's value.

I have a content script that receives the value and checks if activeElement is an `<input>`.

The challenge is when the main document's activeElement is an iframe. I can set `all_frames: true` in manifest, which will find any active `<input>`, but I only want to set the value of the activeElement of the active iframe.

Currently I'm solving this by letting the child content script(s) `blur()` all activeElements except the current one (attaching a handler to `focusin`), but a solution that does not modify the document state would be better imho.

Is it possible to send a message only to the main document and if this one's activeElement is an iframe, get that frameId  (and try again)?

I don't control the web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject a new content script that checks the full hierarchy of frames, including cross-domain frames.

**main content script** asks the background/event page if needed:

```js
if (document.activeElement.matches('input') && window == parent) {
    console.log('Input', document.activeElement);
    document.activeElement.value += ' gotcha!';
} else {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'modifyInput'});
}
```

**[background/event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) script** executes the additional content script in all frames:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse)) {
    if (msg.action == 'modifyInput') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab && sender.tab.id, {
            file: 'modify-input.js',
            allFrames: true,
            matchAboutBlank: true,
            runAt: 'document_end',
        });
    }
});
```

**modify-input.js**, IIFE is used to makes sure garbage collection removes the injected stuff.

```js
;(function() {
if (isInputActive()) {
    if (window == parent) {
        foundTheInput();
    } else {
        askParent();
    }
} else if (isFrameActive()) {
    window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
        if (!e.data || e.data.id != chrome.runtime.id)
            return;
        switch (e.data.action) {
        // request from a child frame
        case 'checkme':
            if (window == parent) {
                confirmChild(e.source);
                window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
            } else {
                askParent();
            }
            break;
        // response from a parent
        case 'confirmed':
            window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
            if (isInputActive()) {
                foundTheInput();
            } else if (isFrameActive()) {
                confirmChild(e.source);
            }
            break;
        }
    });
}

function isInputActive() {
    return document.activeElement.matches('input');
}

function isFrameActive() {
    return document.activeElement.matches('frame, iframe');
}

function askParent() {
    parent.postMessage({id: chrome.runtime.id, action: 'checkme'}, '*');
}

function confirmChild(childWindow) {
    console.log('Frame', document.activeElement);
    childWindow.postMessage({id: chrome.runtime.id, action: 'confirmed': true}, '*');
}

function foundTheInput() {
    console.log('Input', document.activeElement);
    document.activeElement.value += ' gotcha!';
}
})();
```

I didn't test this, but did use and saw similar code previously.

Comment: Interesting solution.. Will need to have a listener on isInputActive case too, though: 
If ```B``` is a subframe of ```A``` and we're searching for the input-activeElement in B.  B will not have a listener with the code as suggested.

Which means I'll need reject messages too (to clean up listeners).

Comment: and A is the main window..

Quite convoluted, but get's get job done - And I haven't found a better way => accepted