# Chrome extension: How to manipulate iframe contents from a different subdomain? (CORS)

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am developing a browser extension that I want to be able to detect the active element within an iframe and paste content in to it using a JavaScript function (held in a content-script of the extension).
It injects a side panel of links, clicking these pastes content in to the active element.

The idea is it will work like this:

[image]

I'm clearly falling foul of the CORS security stuff.  I've researched but all of the solutions I can find seem to be for changing settings server-side - I don't have the luxury unfortunately.

It works perfectly when pasting content in to the host page (top level page) but for the iframe I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
> "https://apps.mydomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin
> "https://other.aspirets.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
> match.

I am using the function found here to try and identify the active element: [Find focused element in document with many iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420219/find-focused-element-in-document-with-many-iframes)

Which is:

```
function getActiveElementV2( document ){
 document = document || window.document;
 // Check if the active element is in the main web or iframe
 if( document.body === document.activeElement 
    || document.activeElement.tagName == 'IFRAME' ){
     // Get iframes
     var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
     for(var i = 0; i<iframes.length; i++ ){
         // Recall
         var focused = getActiveElementV2( iframes[i].contentWindow.document );
         if( focused !== false ){
             return focused; // The focused
         }
     }
 }
else return document.activeElement;
 return false;
};
```

I've tried some suggestions for the manifest file but it's pretty new to me:

```
{
"name": "A Browser Extension",
"description": "A browser extension wot is dead good and that",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 3,
"host_permissions" : [
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
  "*://*.mydomain.com/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite"
],

 
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css" : ["extension-styles.css"],
      "js": ["messages.js", "content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
```

}

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is achieved by running a new instance of the content script in that iframe by using [all_frames option](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, appreciate the suggestion.  I'm not sure it will work for me, I have a side panel appear in the top-level page and clicking links in it pastes content (for example in to a textfield), if I used the all-frames option presumably I'd end up with a side panel in every iframe?

Comment: Then declare a second content script just to run inside the iframe or check location.href. There are no other solutions anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the help @wOxxOm, much appreciated.  I think I'm going to abandoned this, frustratingly the only reason I need to do the above is to return focus to the select area in an iframe *because* there doesn't seem to be a way of putting a variable in to the clipboard without injecting it as text, selecting it (losing focus on my textarea) and copying it.  :-(

Comment: See [Identify true activeElement in a frame hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249715) Another possibility is to simply inject the content script into `frameId` reported by chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm!  I found a better way to copy the content to the clipboard too that doesn't pull focus (navigator.clipboard.writeText) so hopefully that will also help - really appreciate the assistance.